# Restrict admin shares

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, administrator, group-policy

My users need local admin rights but I'd like to restrict the admin shares (c$) to domain admins only. I was reading about adding nt authority\interactive to the local administrator group, but i don't see how to add that group in the [GPO](https://duckduckgo.com/group_Policy). When I change the location to the machine, it doesn't find the interactive group. I'd like to avoid startup scripts of possible and stick to GPO edits

I am running Windows 7 x64 and the server is running server 2008.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: win7 x64 and the gp is on server08

Comment: I tried to add the relevant information to your question. Please review it since I am not sure I understood correctly. Some more details on your network infrastructure would be useful.

Comment: If they are administrators, then they could simply reverse any attempts you make to restrict them.  Administrators are Administrators.

Comment: Not a group policy level rule